# SFSpeechRecognizer online: at which url is sent the request?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm developing an iOS application in Swift that uses SFSpeechRecognizer (package: Speech).

This application is developed for an organization that uses VPN and blocks every request from/to the external network.

This is partial code:

```
let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: self.userLanguageExt))
let recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
let recognitionTask = self.speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: self.recognitionRequest!,resultHandler: { (result, error) in
          if let result = result{
                  ...
          }
          else if error == nil {
                  ...
          }
})
```

I need to know from/to which url is received/sent the RecognizerRequest so I can comunicate it to network team of the organization and they will open the connection to those url. On docs I couldn't find a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

17.250.13.5 (if you check the ip lookup on https://www.iplocation.net/ you find that is an Apple domain)

**How**

I've done tcpdump on my device following this documentation and catched the packets traffic: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace